# Unable to display imdb.com in iframe in angular2 even after using domSanitizer and SafeResourceUrl

Tags: angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

Unable to display www.imdb.com in iframe in angular2 even after using domSanitizer and SafeResourceUrl. But can display Yelp using those.

The error I get is "Refused to display http://www.imdb.com/showtimes/location/US/12345' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following security Policy directive:"frame-ancestors self imdb.com"

Answer (score 1):

This is not an angular issue or whatsoever, imdb.com is sending an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" header. This header prevents showing the site in an iFrame except if a page containing an iFrame is hosted on the same parent domain (imdb.com in this case).

You can find more information on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: but then how would you bypass this issue and show it in a IFrame in a different domain? with Cors?

Comment: @ArghyaRoy either link directly to IMDB or use their API here's a package that uses their api https://www.npmjs.com/package/imdb-api